# Birt not generating PDF and XLS report

Tags: java, spring-mvc, birt

I'm using Birt 4.4 and my html report works fine but xls and pdf files throw *The output format is not supported error*

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: The output format xsl is not supported. 
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.setupRenderOption(EngineTask.java:2031)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:96)
```

I tried setting output format to `xls_spudsoft` and `emitterID` but no luck

Here is the code

```
EXCELRenderOption xlsOptions = new EXCELRenderOption(options);
xlsOptions.setEmitterID("uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.XlsEmitter");
xlsOptions.setOutputFormat("xls_spudsoft");

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + reportName + "\"");
xlsOptions.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
```

any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found what was the problem, in case someone wants to know how to fix this. Specify emitter for pdf report   `pdfOptions.setEmitterID(RenderOption.OUTPUT_EMITTERID_PDF)` and for xls it was missing `uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel` from classpath